# How to reduce SQLite memory consumption?

Tags: c, performance, sqlite, memory-consumption

I'm looking for ways to reduce memory consumption by SQLite3 in my application.

At each execution it creates a table with the following schema:

```
(main TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE, count INTEGER DEFAULT 0)
```

After that, the database is filled with 50k operations per second. Write only.

When an item already exists, it updates "count" using an update query (I think this is called UPSERT). These are my queries:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO table (main) VALUES (@SEQ);
UPDATE tables SET count=count+1 WHERE main = @SEQ;
```

This way, with 5 million operations per transaction, I can write really fast to the DB.

I don't really care about disk space for this problem, but I have a very limited RAM space. Thus, I can't waste too much memory.

sqlite3_user_memory() informs that its memory consumption grows to almost 3GB during the execution. If I limit it to 2GB through sqlite3_soft_heap_limit64(), database operations' performance drops to almost zero when reaching 2GB.

I had to raise cache size to 1M (page size is default) to reach a desirable performance.

What can I do to reduce memory consumption?

Comment: How big is the table?

Comment: @CL. 35M rows, each main entry is a string with 30+ chars.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would:

- prepare the statements (if you're not doing it already)
- lower the amount of INSERTs per transaction (10 sec = 500,000 sounds appropriate)
- use `PRAGMA locking_mode = EXCLUSIVE;` if you can

Also, (I'm not sure if you know) the `PRAGMA cache_size` is in pages, not in MBs. Make sure you define your target memory in as `PRAGMA cache_size * PRAGMA page_size` or in SQLite >= 3.7.10 you can also do `PRAGMA cache_size = -kibibytes;`. Setting it to 1 M(illion) would result in 1 or 2 GB.

I'm curious how `cache_size`  helps in INSERTs though...

You can also try and benchmark if the `PRAGMA temp_store = FILE;` makes a difference.

And of course, whenever your database is not being written to:

- `PRAGMA shrink_memory;`
- `VACUUM;`

Depending on what you're doing with the database, these might also help:

- `PRAGMA auto_vacuum = 1|2;`
- `PRAGMA secure_delete = ON;`

---

I ran some tests with the following pragmas:

```
busy_timeout=0;
cache_size=8192;
encoding="UTF-8";
foreign_keys=ON;
journal_mode=WAL;
legacy_file_format=OFF;
synchronous=NORMAL;
temp_store=MEMORY;
```

### Test #1:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO test (time) VALUES (?);
UPDATE test SET count = count + 1 WHERE time = ?;
```

Peaked ~109k updates per second.

### Test #2:

```
REPLACE INTO test (time, count) VALUES
(?, coalesce((SELECT count FROM test WHERE time = ? LIMIT 1) + 1, 1));
```

Peaked at ~120k updates per second.

---

I also tried `PRAGMA temp_store = FILE;` and the updates dropped by ~1-2k per second.

---

For 7M updates in a transaction, the `journal_mode=WAL` is slower than all the others.

---

I populated a database with 35,839,987 records and now my setup is taking nearly 4 seconds per each batch of 65521 updates - however, it doesn't even reach 16 MB of memory consumption.

---

Ok, here's another one:

> **Indexes on INTEGER PRIMARY KEY columns (don't do it)**
>
> When you create a column with INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, SQLite uses this
>   column as the key for (index to) the table structure. This is a hidden
>   index (as it isn't displayed in SQLite_Master table) on this column.
>   Adding another index on the column is not needed and will never be
>   used. In addition it will slow INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE operations
>   down.

You seem to be defining your PK as NOT NULL + UNIQUE. PK is UNIQUE implicitly.

Answer (score 20):

It seems that the high memory consumption may be caused by the fact that too many operations are concentrated in one big transaction. Trying to commit smaller transaction like per 1M operations may help. 5M operations per transaction consumes too much memory.

However, we'd balance the operation speed and memory usage.

If smaller transaction is not an option, `PRAGMA shrink_memory` may be a choice.

Use `sqlite3_status()` with `SQLITE_STATUS_MEMORY_USED` to trace the dynamic memory allocation and locate the bottleneck.

Comment: I already tried reduce transactions to 1M. It still consumes same RAM, but becomes much more slow.

Comment: there is a `PRAGMA shrink_memory` is supposed to make a database connection to free up as many memory as it can.

Comment: your comment made me realize that i was using an old version of sqlite3. I had 3.7.9, that doesn't support PRAGMA shrink_memory or sqlite3_db_release_memory() . Thanks for that =) Using PRAGMA shrink_memory + sqlite3_db_memory_release(), i see memory consumption dropping really fast when this function is called. I think this just releases all cache and heap memory, because insert performance also drops until cache gets filled again and memory consumption back closer to what it was before. It's not perfect, but this can be a useful solution =)

Comment: i get syntax error when running `sqlite3_status();`

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that all the operations in one transaction are distributed all over the table so that all pages of the table need to be accessed, the size of the working set is:

- about 1 GB for the table's data, plus
- about 1 GB for the index on the `main` column, plus
- about 1 GB for the original data of all the table's pages changed in the transaction (probably all of them).

---

You could try to reduce the amount of data that gets changed for each operation by moving the `count` column into a separate table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE main_lookup(main TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, rowid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE counters(rowid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, count INTEGER DEFAULT 0);
```

Then, for each operation:

```sql
SELECT rowid FROM main_lookup WHERE main = @SEQ;
if not exists:
    INSERT INTO main_lookup(main) VALUES(@SEQ);
    --read the inserted rowid
    INSERT INTO counters VALUES(@rowid, 0);
UPDATE counters SET count=count+1 WHERE rowid = @rowid;
```

In C, the inserted `rowid` is read with [sqlite3_last_insert_rowid](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html).

Doing a separate `SELECT` and `INSERT` is not any slower than `INSERT OR IGNORE`; SQLite does the same work in either case.

This optimization is useful only if most operations update a counter that already exists.

Comment: Didn't work. It became slower and memory consumption is higher.

Answer (score 2):

In the spirit of brainstorming I will venture an answer. I have not done any testing like this fellow:

[Improve INSERT-per-second performance of SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/how-do-i-improve-the-performance-of-sqlite)

My hypothesis is that the index on the text primary key might be more RAM-intensive than a couple of indexes on two integer columns (what you'd need to simulate a hashed-table).

EDIT: Actually, you dont' even need a primary key for this:

```
      create table foo( slot integer, myval text, occurrences int);
      create index ix_foo on foo(slot);  // not a unique index
```

An integer primary key (or a non-unique index on slot) would leave you with no quick way to determine if your text value were already on file. So to address that requirement, you might try implementing something I suggested to another poster, simulating a hashed-key:

[SQLite Optimization for Millions of Entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807117/sqlite-optimization-for-millions-of-entries/3807246#3807246)

A hash-key-function would allow you to determine where the text-value would be stored if it did exist.

http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall08/cos521/hash.pdf
http://www.fearme.com/misc/alg/node28.html
http://cs.mwsu.edu/~griffin/courses/2133/downloads/Spring11/p677-pearson.pdf