# Rails SQLite performance optimization

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, performance, sqlite, optimization

My rails app collects a lot of data from the web, running ETL on hundreds of thousands of incoming records - selects, updates, and inserts - on a normalized database of about a dozen tables. What is the best reliable way to speed up performance of my sqlite database?

I have set up indexes on all fields I search by, and wrapped the main loop into a single transaction.

Are there any other standard practices, like database settings, that would speed up SQLite?

Comment: Profile, and see where your problems really are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have to disagree with the other answers suggestiong you to switch to mysql or postgres without knowing more about why your code isnt running fast enough. [People tend to agree SQLite can handle large amounts of data in a performance oriented system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160987/can-sqlite-handle-90-million-records). I would suggest to post some code of some scenarios that you do often and lets see if we can think of a better way to do them. If you are using the same flawed approach in SQLite and mysql i doubt you will see much better gains.

> SQLite is capable of being extremely fast. If you are seeing speeds slower than other DB systems such as MySQL or PostGres, then you are not utilizing SQLite to its full potential. Optimizing for speed appears to be the second priority of D. Richard Hipp, the author and maintainer of SQLite. The first is data integrity and venerability. Read more about some optimizing you can do [here](http://web.utk.edu/~jplyon/sqlite/SQLite_optimization_FAQ.html)

also are you

Inserting the data in bulk transactions? 
and you should try and order the data when importing it
Maybe even consider redoing your indexes at night or a period of less activity

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is not a good choice if you have lots of data. If you have the option, switch to mysql or postgres. Both are easy to install and should perform better.