# File size limit for SQLite on 32bit system

Tags: sqlite

I'm using sqlite as temporary storage to calculate statistic about moderately large data set.
I'm wondering what will happen if my database exceed 2GB on 32 bit system. (I can't currently change the system to 64 bit)

Does it use memory mapped files and break if size of file exceed addressable memory? (like mongodb)

Comment: possible duplicate of [is there a limit to the size of a sqlite database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777954/is-there-a-limit-to-the-size-of-a-sqlite-database)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According sqlite documentation, maximum size of database file is ~140 terabytes and is practically limited by os/file system.

You can read more here (note the ***Pages*** section): http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html

Comment: thank you. I've omitted that page in google results as I haven't expect to find such information on fileformat page

Comment: You've intrigued me with this question (I've never dealt whit such huge sqlite databases) :) I've experimented with 5.5GB test db and found no problems at all on 32-bit linux with xfs file system.

Answer (score 1):

Though this is an old question, but let me share my findings for people who reach this question.

Although Sqlite documentation states that maximum size of database file is ~140 terabytes but your OS imposes it's own restrictions on maximum file size for any type of file.

For e.g. if you are using FAT32 disk on Windows, maximum file size that I could achieve for sqLite was **2GB.**
(According to Microsoft site, limit on **FAT 32** system is **4GB** but still my sqlite db size was restricted to **2GB**).
While on Linux , I was able to reach 3 GB (where I stopped. it could have reached more size)

Answer (score 0):

Find out your file system type of the partition. Remember that the file size limit its not dependent with the OS 32-bit or 64-bit, but with partition type of your hard disk.

[See Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits)