# Will SQLite performance degrade if the database size is greater than 2 gigabytes?

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

Last year when I checked about SQLite on their web site, the recommended SQLite database size was 2 gigabytes. But now, I could not find that recommendation again.

So has anyone tried to work with an SQLite database that is bigger than 2 gigabytes using latest version of it? How well did SQLite perform?

P.S: I would like to make a mobile application that requires big database (for example storing Wikipedia articles) that works locally.

Comment: Most apps use apis.  But i commend you for trying I wonder what you did in end did u go with sql lite or did u use an api. Am wanting my app to work off kine to. 

U also have to think how will u support a 2gb plus file on someones fone u cant really.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

There is no 2 GB limit.

SQLite database files have a maximum size of about 140 TB.

On a phone, the size of the storage (a few GB) will limit your database file size,
while the memory size will limit how much data you can retrieve from a query.
Furthermore, Android cursors have a limit of 1 MB for the results.

---

The database size will, by itself, not affect your performance.
Your queries will be fast as long as they do not access more data than fits into the DB's [page cache](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_cache_size) (2 MB by default).

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer. But what I want to know is that how sqlite will perform depending on its database size.

Comment: I’ve read other answers on StackOverflow with people successfully using much larger databases (even up to 100GB), so I’m pretty sure SQLite can handle 2GB just fine.

Comment: i am assuming this limit does not hold for python sqlite module as long as you can iterate one row at a time with the cursor

Comment: @PirateApp Yeah it's unclear to me what "Android cursors have a limit of 1 MB for the results" means... does that mean each row can be up to 1MB in size since you can iterate the cursor one row at a time?  And if not, how do you deal with larger data sets?

Comment: As of release 3.33.0 (2020-08-14), the maximum size is 281 TB. https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html

Answer (score 31):

Usually the larger the database the more data you have in it. The more data you have, the longer searches may take. They don't have to, it depends on a search.

As for inserts, they may take longer if you have many indexes on a table. Rebuilding an index may take some time, so expect insert speed degradation with the amount of data.

Updates may also be slower - fitting rows must be found first (search), then values have to be changed (may trigger an index rebuild).

I am telling you this from experience: if you expect a lot of data in your database, consider splitting it into multiple databases. This works if your data is gathered daily and you can create a database for each day. May make your search code more complex, but will speed things up for limited searches/

Comment: Although I agree with your statements, I think that if you're creating an app on a mobile phone, creating many files is probably not the best idea... It uses more disk space to have many separate files.

Comment: @AlexisWilke the amount of space lost for each file is negligible on most filesystems for files with reasonable size (say, 1mb+)

Comment: @Dariusz Hi, If I want to save image tiles which each tile is about 20kb, and totall size will be about 40TB how can I handel adding data into sqlite database?do you have any idea to increase insert performance?total number of tiles is about 1831292252

Comment: @MajidHojati if you have no indexes, FKs, etc. then in this case insert performance should be capped solely by your disk performance

Comment: @Dariusz so I have to insert data first and later enable indexes on tables. right?