# Change and save only one row in a file

Tags: r, csv, flat-file, sqldf

I wonder if there is something in R that allows me to update a file rather than saving it all the data.

Maybe there is something like `sqldf::read.csv.sql` for saving.

---

OK

Let's say I have iris data stored as .csv:

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
```

But I have realised, that second flower is virginica, so I want change second row to:

```
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  virginica
```

I know, that I can read file, change Species, and save it again, but the more rows (i.e. > 10 <sup>6</sup>) I have in my file, the less efficient this method is.

Comment: Can you narrow down your question? What kind of file are we talking about? For text files, the answer is probably no.

Comment: The write functions all have append options. Agree the question is too unclear to support a coding response. You should edit your question to include more specifics.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11067/is-there-a-way-to-modify-a-file-in-place

Answer (score 1):

In general, R is really not meant for in-place file editing, and I'm aware of no (currently available) tools that support it in any context. Even unixy-tools like `sed` do fast editing but still do not do it technically "in-place" (even if it hides how it does it). (There might be some that do, but perhaps not with the ease-of-access that you want.)

There is one notable exception, a file format that is *designed* for in-place editing (well, interaction). It includes significant in-place addition, filtering, replacement, and deletion operators. And for the most part, it generally does this without needing to increase the file size while doing so. It's **[SQLite](http://sqlite.org/)**.

For example,

```
library(DBI)
# library(RSQLite) # don't need to load it, just need to have it available
fname <- "./iris.sqlite3"
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), fname)
file.info(fname)$size
# [1] 0
dbWriteTable(con, "iris", iris)
# [1] TRUE
file.info(fname)$size
# [1] 16384
dbGetQuery(con, "select * from iris where [Sepal.Length]=4.7 and [Sepal.Width]=3.2 and [Petal.Length]=1.6")
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          4.7         3.2          1.6         0.2  setosa
file.info(fname)$size
# [1] 16384
dbExecute(con, "update iris set [Species]='virginica' where [Sepal.Length]=4.7 and [Sepal.Width]=3.2 and [Petal.Length]=1.6")
# [1] 1
dbGetQuery(con, "select * from iris where [Sepal.Length]=4.7 and [Sepal.Width]=3.2 and [Petal.Length]=1.6")
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
# 1          4.7         3.2          1.6         0.2 virginica
dbDisconnect(con)
file.info(fname)$size
# [1] 16384
```

### Pros

- It is [cross-platform](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html). It is more prolific than most people realize, being a required internal component of the Firefox browser and the Android OS. ([Many others](https://www.sqlite.org/famous.html), too.)
- Additionally, drivers exist in most programming languages, including R, python, ruby, and many too many to list here.
- There is really no practical limits to the amount of data that can be stored in a single SQLite file. It theoretically supports up to 140TB (https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html), though if you're getting this large, there are many (justified) arguments towards different solutions.
- Pulling data is built on the SQL standard, and though it is not 100% compliant, it is [pretty darn close](https://www.sqlite.org/lang.html). Query time/performance is predicated on your query size, but generally pretty fast (ref: [Will SQLite performance degrade if the database size is greater than 2 gigabytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451624/will-sqlite-performance-degrade-if-the-database-size-is-greater-than-2-gigabytes))
- In fact, it can be [faster](https://www.sqlite.org/fasterthanfs.html) than individual file operations.

### Cons

- There will be "overhead" in the file size. Notable is that `iris` takes under 7K of memory (see `object.size(iris)`) yet the filesize starts at 16K. With larger data, the gap *ratio* (file size to actual data) will shrink. (I did the same things with `ggplot2::diamonds`; the object is 3456376 bytes and the file size is 3780608, less than 10% larger.)
- The file size will increase when SQLite deems necessary. This is based on many factors outside the scope of R and this question/answer.
- If you delete a lot of data, the file size does not immediately reduce to accommodate that ... see [change sqlite file size after "DELETE FROM table"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2143800/3358272) (hint: `vacuum`)
- There are many tools that will easily/immediately import data from this file format, but notably absent is Excel and Access. It is feasible with [SQLite-ODBC](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/), but takes a little elbow-grease to do it. (I'm fine with it, but not all users will be, and some enterprise networks make this step difficult or specifically disallowed.)

### SQLite-file-as-CSV

You can treat it like a file when importing, if you want to import all of it:

```
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), fname)
iris2 <- dbGetQuery(con, "select * from iris")
dbDisconnect(con)
```

as compared to

```
iris2 <- read.csv("iris.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

If you want to get fancy:

```
import_sqlite <- function(fname, tablename = NA) {
  if (length(tablename) > 1L) {
    warning("the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used")
    tablename <- tablename[[1L]]
  }
  con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), fname)
  on.exit(DBI::dbDisconnect(con), add = TRUE)
  available_tables <- DBI::dbListTables(con)
  if (length(available_tables) == 0L) {
    stop("no tables found")
  } else if (is.na(tablename)) {
    if (length(available_tables) == 1L) {
      tablename <- available_tables
    }
  }
  if (tablename %in% available_tables) {
    tablename <- DBI::dbQuoteIdentifier(con, tablename)
    qry <- sprintf("select * from %s", tablename)
    out <- tryCatch(list(data = DBI::dbGetQuery(con, DBI::SQL(qry)),
                         err = NULL),
                    error = function(e) list(data = NULL, err = e))
    if (! is.null(out$err)) {
      stop("[sqlite error] ", out$err$message)
    } else {
      return(out$data)
    }    
  } else {
    stop(sprintf("table %s not found", DBI::dbQuoteIdentifier(con, tablename)))
  }
}
head(import_sqlite("iris.sqlite3"))
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

(I'm not offering that function as anything other than a proof-of-concept that you can interact with the single file as if it were a CSV. There are some safeguards in there but is really just a hack for the sake of this question.)