# JAVA SQLite shows "database disk image malformed error" after reaching a file size of 2 GB on windows?

Tags: sql, windows, sqlite, ubuntu, windows-8.1

I am using sqlite db. This has happened to me four times that as soon as db size reaches 2 GB, I get this error. Any ideas how to fix this?

Trial 1&2:

```
OS: Windows 8.1
File System: NTFS     
SQLITE : 3
Eclipse: Mars
JDBC: sqlite-jdbc-3.6.7
```

Trial 3:

```
OS: Windows 2008 server
File System: NTFS     
SQLITE : 3
Eclipse: Mars
JDBC: sqlite-jdbc-3.6.7
```

Trial 4:

```
OS: Windows 2008 server
File System: FAT32
SQLITE : 3
Eclipse: Mars
JDBC: sqlite-jdbc-3.6.7
```

While on ubuntu file size of 5 GB is reached without any problem

```
OS: Linux
File System: ext4
SQLITE : 3
Eclipse: Mars
JDBC: sqlite-jdbc-3.6.7
```

Comment: What filesystem is being used? [Sqlite itself has no such internal limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451624/is-sqlite-performance-will-be-degraded-if-database-size-is-more-than-2-gigabytes); the "magic 2GB" first makes me think there is a write/copy corruption elsewhere.

Comment: @Akshay `Windows 8.1` is not a filesystem, is your hard disk formatted as FAT, FAT32 or NTFS or some other combination

Comment: @Ferrybig Hard disk is in NTFS fromat