# How to create a huge SQlite database when an app is first opened in Java

Tags: java, sqlite

So I have this huge list of items (about 700000 lines) that I would like to immediately insert into an SQLite database when an app is first made. I have already created a method to check whether or not it is the first time the app has been made (using sharedpreferences), and have created a huge list of commands to run (some examples:

```
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO topenings (name,cust,color) VALUES('White - Modern Defense: Ipatov,Alexander - Shtembuliak,E: Pan-Am Intercollegiate 1/2-1/2','d2d4 g7g6 c2c4 f8g7 e2e4 d7d6 b1c3 e7e5 d4d5 a7a5 f1d3 b8a6 g1e2 d8h4 e1g1 g8h6 f2f3 e8g8 d1e1 h4e7 g1h1 c8d7 c1e3 f7f5 e4f5 h6f5 e3f2 a6c5 d3c2 g7h6 e2g3 b7b6 g3f5 g6f5 f3f4 a8e8 f4e5 d6e5 d5d6 c7d6 c3d5 e7g7 d5b6 d7c6 b6d5 c6d5 c4d5 c5d7 a1d1 h6g5 e1a5 e5e4 f2d4 g5f6 d4f6 d7f6 d1e1 e8e5 a5b6 g7e7 a2a4 f6g4 h2h3 g4f6 c2d1 g8h8 a4a5 f8g8 a5a6 f5f4 b6b7 f4f3 b7e7 f3g2 h1h2 g2f1N e1f1 e5e7 f1f6 e4e3 f6e6 e7f7 d1g4 h7h5 g4h5 f7f2 h2h1 g8c8 e6h6 h8g7 h6g6 g7f8 g6g2 c8c1 h1h2 f2d2 h5e2 d2b2 ','White')");

sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO topenings (name,cust,color) VALUES('Black - Modern Defense: Ipatov,Alexander - Shtembuliak,E: Pan-Am Intercollegiate 1/2-1/2','d2d4 g7g6 c2c4 f8g7 e2e4 d7d6 b1c3 e7e5 d4d5 a7a5 f1d3 b8a6 g1e2 d8h4 e1g1 g8h6 f2f3 e8g8 d1e1 h4e7 g1h1 c8d7 c1e3 f7f5 e4f5 h6f5 e3f2 a6c5 d3c2 g7h6 e2g3 b7b6 g3f5 g6f5 f3f4 a8e8 f4e5 d6e5 d5d6 c7d6 c3d5 e7g7 d5b6 d7c6 b6d5 c6d5 c4d5 c5d7 a1d1 h6g5 e1a5 e5e4 f2d4 g5f6 d4f6 d7f6 d1e1 e8e5 a5b6 g7e7 a2a4 f6g4 h2h3 g4f6 c2d1 g8h8 a4a5 f8g8 a5a6 f5f4 b6b7 f4f3 b7e7 f3g2 h1h2 g2f1N e1f1 e5e7 f1f6 e4e3 f6e6 e7f7 d1g4 h7h5 g4h5 f7f2 h2h1 g8c8 e6h6 h8g7 h6g6 g7f8 g6g2 c8c1 h1h2 f2d2 h5e2 d2b2 ','Black')");
)
```

(This is a small chess app I am making to train openings)

I made a python script to create these, but I have hundreds of thousands of these lines that I need to add to an SQLite database, and trying to do them through android returns the code too large error. Is there any way I can create this database immediately?

Note: I am open to the idea of a pre-populated database, but I do not yet have this SQlite database created and do not see a good way to create this database and insert it into the app

Comment: "trying to do them through android returns the code too large error". Could you add to your question the full error message?

Answer (score 0):

Chak,

SQLite database files have a maximum size of approximately 140TB.

https://www.sqlite.org/features.html

https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14454573/5620039

One way to do this is to first create the empty database.
When the application is opened for the first time, it will return the 700000 rows from a webservice / api and then be inserted into the sqlite database.

Note the android memory limit for cursors.