# What is a maximum size of SQLite database?

Tags: database, sqlite

I'm planning to create which extensively uses local DB. DB would contain approx 150 tables , tables would have up to 23000 entries and about 150 columns with text, each table has 
town name / KM and numbers only. Can I use SQlite for this purpose

thanks

Comment: possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777954/is-there-a-limit-to-the-size-of-a-sqlite-database

Comment: http://sqlite.org/limits.html