# sqlite channge max column limitation

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to create a database with a matrix with about 3000 columns and 2500 rows on sqlite. However, it has the 2000 column limitation. I downloaded sqlite-amalgamation from
https://www.sqlite.org/download.html and changed SQLITE_MAX_COLUMN to 3000 on sqlite3.c file. My O.S. is Ubuntu. I tried to uninstall sqlite3 with

```
sudo apt-get remove sqlite3
sudo apt-get autoremove sqlite3
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge sqlite3
```

It seems sqlite3 is uninstalled. But when I type **import sqlite3** in anaconda spyder, it seems sqlite3 is still exists. I restarted my computer but nothing changed.
However, I tried to compile modified sqlite3. I run

```
./configure
```

Then I run

```
make
```

and got this error

```
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

And Finally nothing changed and when I use the following code to import the 2500*3000 matrix in my excel file to my database

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
connection_obj = sqlite3.connect('MyDataBase.db') 
MyTable = pd.read_excel('my_excel.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1')
MyTable.to_sql('MyTable', connection_obj, index=False)
connection_obj.commit()
```

I get this error

```
OperationalError: too many columns on MyTable
```

What should I do?
Thanks.

Comment: You ask for a huge number of columns. Do you really need this much ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a table with a huge number of columns

```sql
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    RowID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Column1 REAL,
    Column2 REAL,
    ...
    Column3000 REAL
);
```

Try reorganizing it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    RowID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ColumnID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Value REAL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Row, ColumnID)
);
```

That way, you only need 3 columns, and the SQLite table can hold [up to 2<sup>64</sup> rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546947/maximum-number-of-rows-in-a-sqlite-table), well more than enough to handle the 7.5 million cells from your Excel sheet.

Here's a Python generator function that may help with the transformation.  (Disclaimer: I have only tested it with the builtin `list` of `list`, not with Pandas table objects.)

```py
def row_col_enumerate(matrix):
    for (row, row_data) in enumerate(matrix):
        for (col, value) in enumerate(row_data):
            yield (row, col, value)
```

Example:

```py
>>> for rcv in row_col_enumerate([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]):
...     print(rcv)
...
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 1, 2)
(0, 2, 3)
(1, 0, 4)
(1, 1, 5)
(1, 2, 6)
(2, 0, 7)
(2, 1, 8)
(2, 2, 9)
```