# How does SQLite handle huge databases?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

**First**, what is the limit of a ***SQLite*** database? Is there any?

**Second**, if SQLite DB file is stored on a disk (not in RAM), and is several Gigs or Ters in size, how does that affect the performance when querying it?

I'm writing a genomics program in Python and like the convenient maintenance of SQLite, but not sure about its performance with large databases.

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html - _"The largest possible setting for SQLITE_MAX_PAGE_COUNT is 2147483646. When used with the maximum page size of 65536, this gives a maximum SQLite database size of about 140 terabytes."_ I'm assuming you're talking about file size limit. There are other types of limit (depth, # terms, etc.) listed on that page.

Comment: As for performance - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784173/what-are-the-performance-characteristics-of-sqlite-with-very-large-database-file