# Persistent dictionary where keys can be anything hashable

Tags: python, dictionary, persistence, memoization

I'm implementing a small "persistent" version of [functools.lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache), where "persistent" means that the cache is not destroyed between subsequent runs.  To this end, I thought I could simply replace the dictionary that `functools.lru_cache` uses by a [shelve](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/shelve.html) object, but I'm running into `shelve`s requirement for keys to be `str`ings.  I tried to fix it by using `str(hash(...).to_int(...))`, but `hash(...)` is not identical for identical objects between different runs of the cpython interpreter.

Is there any class like `shelve` that allows for any hashable key, rather than just `str`ings, while being accessible like a dictionary transparently?

Some details: my cache might be in the order of 100MB.  It is somewhat frequently read and infrequently written.

Comment: one question pops in my head, why not stringify your key `str()`?

Comment: @zeapo As in `str(bytes(hash(...).to_int(...)))`?  I thought of that after posting this question.  It hurts me on the inside, though ;-)

Comment: @zeapo Just realised that `hash(...)` is not consistent between different cpython runs.

Comment: @zeapo But, I could just run `str(...)` on my key directly as long as its string-representation is reasonably short.  That probably has some caveats but it will probably do for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

The concrete solution really depends on your needs, but it is likely you'll find that using a database is the best solution for your case. You can also use `pickle` instead of shelve, but that has its downsides of course.

- is the cache big?

then you need a solution which avoids reading/writing the entire cache on each access (e.g. a pickle-based solution), e.g. a DB.

- is it accessed frequently?

then you probably also want an in-memory caching to avoid the frequent slow external accesses.

Quick googling found this: [persistentdict](https://code.google.com/p/persistentdict/).

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837229/large-python-dictionary-with-persistence-storage-for-quick-look-ups).

Comment: Wouldn't most, if not all, databases still require that the keys are strings?

Answer (score 0):

Could subclassing `Shelf` work the way you want?

```
from shelve import Shelf

class SubShelf(Shelf):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        h = str(hash(key))
        super().__setitem__(h, val)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        h = str(hash(key))
        return super().__getitem__(h)
```

Comment: That doesn't work, because `hash(key)` is not identical for identical keys between subsequent runs of the Python interpreter.