# Most disk space efficient memory mapped dictionary for 20 million key-value pairs, speed not too much of a concern

Tags: python, database, dictionary

I have about 20 million key-value pairs . I need to create two dictionaries.

First dictionary:
The values are ints, from 0 to 20 million. The keys are strings of length 40 characters, for example '36ae99662ec931a3c20cffdecb39b69a8f7f23fd'.

Second dictionary:
Reverse of the first dictionary. The keys are ints, from 0 to 20 million. The values are strings of length 40 characters, for example '36ae99662ec931a3c20cffdecb39b69a8f7f23fd'.

I think for the second dictionary, there are more options, since the index can just be used as the key. For the second option, it looks like sqlite3 is promising.

Lookup speed is not too important, 1 second look up should be okay. The main concern is I don't have too much space to store the dictionary.

As for my best guess for the first type of dictionary, From this SO post

[*large* python dictionary with persistence storage for quick look-ups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837229/large-python-dictionary-with-persistence-storage-for-quick-look-ups)

It looks like dbm would be a decent solution for the first type of dictionary since all the keys and values are stored as bytes, though the answer was given 7 years ago in 2012. I am not sure if it is a decent solution today.

Answer (score 1):

The strings look hexadecimal. In that case you could start by using `binascii.unhexlify` to convert them to binary strings. That is a 50% space saving right there.

```
In [2]: import binascii

In [3]: binascii.unhexlify('36ae99662ec931a3c20cffdecb39b69a8f7f23fd')
Out[3]: b'6\xae\x99f.\xc91\xa3\xc2\x0c\xff\xde\xcb9\xb6\x9a\x8f\x7f#\xfd'

In [4]: len(binascii.unhexlify('36ae99662ec931a3c20cffdecb39b69a8f7f23fd'))
Out[4]: 20
```

20 million key/value pairs isn't all that much for a modern computer. Looking at the size of the pure data (20 bytes for the string, 4 bytes for the integer) we're talking around half a GB.

```
In [5]: 20e6 * (20 + 4) / 1e9
Out[5]: 0.48
```

The most *space efficient* way is to just make an array of key/value pairs, *sorted* by the key. Since we *know* that every pair is 24 bytes, accessing them in a mmapped file is trivial; you can just use *slicing*. And I would use a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) for look-up.

This has *no* storage overhead. But *inserting* a value would be inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your second dictionary is just a reverse of the first, I think you probably want to use a single table database. You can have a primary key and then an index on the strings as well for fast lookups. Something like sqlite makes sense.

What size memory are you dealing with? It could still be in memory for python but all depends on how much memory you have.

Comment: I have about 12 gigs of ram. Does sqlite do string index? I looked it up but couldn't find anything