# Split large sqlite table by sessionid field

Tags: sqlite, refactoring-databases

I am relatively new to sql(ite), and I'm learning as I go while working on a new project.
We have got millions of transaction rows in one "data" table, one field being a "sessionid" field.

Since I want to concentrate on in-session activity for now, I primarily need to look only at transactions from the same sessions.

My intuition now is, that it would be a lot faster if I separate the database by sessions into many single session tables, than always querying for a single sessionid, and then proceeding. My question: is that correct? will that make a difference?

Even if not: Could you help me out and tell me, how I could split the one "data" table rows into many session-specific tables, the rows staying the same? Plus one table which relates sessionIds to their tables?

Thanks!

---

A friend just told me, the splitting-into-tables thing would be extremely unflexible, and I should try adding a distinct index instead for the different sessionId rows to access single sessions faster. Any thoughts on that and how to do it best?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you having any specific performance bottleneck with it till now? If yes, please describe it.

Having one table per session will probably speed lookups/indexes (for `INSERT`s) things up.

SQLite doesn't impose a limit on the number of tables, so you should be okay.

One other solution that provides easier maintenance, is if you create one table per day/week.

Depending on how long your sessions last, this could be feasible or not.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/811862/89771