# using dbcontext in wpf

Tags: wpf, dbcontext

I am developing a wpf desktop app using vs2013. And I am using sqlite as database. To perform operations on database, I am using dbcontext class. Now using this procedure, I have the whole database object in my class and on this object I perform operations( I hope my understanding is corect). After performing operation, I garbage collect that object. Now what if my db size grows to 1gb. Is it a good idea to use this procedure? If not what are the other alyernatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework does not load the entire database into memory. The DbContext performs SQL queries when you use it, so you shouldn't have problems with a growing database.
I don't know about the performance of huge SQLite databases, though. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784173/what-are-the-performance-characteristics-of-sqlite-with-very-large-database-file) for some perspective on that.

Comment: Ok, just again for confirmation: I've this code:                   using (var context = new TeamSystemContext())
            {
                var tags = from a in context.TeamTags
                              where a.TeamId == p
                              select a;

                return tags.ToList();
            }                                                                   When i put a breakpoint on context object and have a look at it, it shows the complete database object. So I thought the whole database is loaded into memory. What I am understanding wrong here?

Comment: The context *does* represent the entire database. The data itself is only loaded when necessary (in your code, when you call `ToList`).