# Slow query in SQLite with index and what is better?

Tags: sql, database, performance, sqlite

I'd like to do analytics on a large table (10,000,000 rows / 40 columns). So I've loaded the table into SQLite to query it. I have a query like

```
SELECT x, y FROM table WHERE x in (10,20,30)
```

Now I've noticed that this is incredibly slow in SQLite, since I have an index on `x` only. I guess this is due to hard-drive access which jumps between different places in the file. A covering index `(x, y)` would solve the issue, but I don't want to create a covering index for every type of query I do.

So my question is: Can I tune SQLite to be faster? Or alternatively which database is likely to be faster than my solution (are other SQL DBs faster)?

PS: What's the actual reason the query is so slow?

Comment: How many records does you query return?

Comment: Here are two resources to think about:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784173/what-are-the-performance-characteristics-of-sqlite-with-very-large-database-file and https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html.

Comment: The query returns a sizeable chunk of the rows. It depends on the analysis but can be as much as 10%. I've already tried VACUUM etc and couldn't find anything else on the internet. And this is very slow only the first time it is executed - so most likely something related to hard-drive?

Comment: Creating index on `(x, y)` pair has no sense here. You don't search by those columns, only by `x`. Index has nothing to do with what you return from the query.

Comment: @Googie: Oh, it makes a speed difference of at least a factor 1000. With the double index, the engine doesn't have to read the rows at all and only reads the index. With a single index it constantly jumps between index and row data.

Comment: Can you explain how this query is useful?

Comment: @Aducci I'm sure what the question is. I basically sub-select by some variable and I want to get (part of) the rows in that table.

Comment: @Gerenuk What do you do with the result? Is this a one time thing? Is it going to be part of a report?

Comment: @Aducci It is like a one-time thing. Someday I decide to do some analysis, so I load these rows into memory (computer program). I might do this query or something similar next day again. Depending on the analysis.