# sqlite3 DB read write is very very slow even with 10 MB footprint and single user application

Tags: sqlite, adodb

we have recently moved to plain vanilla sqlite3 from sql anywhere database.
In our application, we use sqlite db to maintain client side meta data
information. The db instance can be used by one client installation only.
we are noticing huge performance impact wrt DB calls. As we keep writing
into the DB, the operations become hopelessly slow though the DB file does
not grow beyond 10 MB or so.

Our application connects to DB via ADO layer and use to work well with SQL
Anywhere. After a threshold, all read and write operations become expensive.

we have tried with following PRAGMA options but to minimum effect:

```
synchronous=OFF

journal_mode=OFF;

cache_size=10000;

temp_store=2;

read_uncommitted=True;

count_changes=OFF;
```

Please suggest.

Comment: This might be useful:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/improve-insert-per-second-performance-of-sqlite

Comment: And this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784173/what-are-the-performance-characteristics-of-sqlite-with-very-large-database-file

Comment: And a blog:  http://blog.devart.com/increasing-sqlite-performance.html

Comment: Your problem is probably not the write speed itself (and your settings are unsafe; don't use them) by the actual queries you're using. Show them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the performance characteristics of sqlite with very large database files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784173/what-are-the-performance-characteristics-of-sqlite-with-very-large-database-file)