# Python SQLite3 Simultaneous Access of Large DB

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlite, large-data, ray

I have a large dataset (~300GB) and access to a machine which can fit it into RAM (but not multiple times). I need to access sections of this dataset, perform calculations on them and then write the results to a file. My idea was to set up a database using SQLite3 to store the data and then query this database to read out the sections of data.

I have done this using [Ray](https://www.ray.io/) to set up a process (hereafter DB process) which can query the database and return the (few) results. The other (31) processes send their requests do the DB process, get the results, do the calculations and, once they have done all their work, write out to a file. Here is an example snippet of code:

```
import sqlite3
import ray
import numpy as np

@ray.remote(num_cpus=2, max_concurrency=1)
class DatabaseHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.con = sqlite3.connect('../Data/databse.db')

    def query(self, value1, value2):
        cur = self.con.cursor()

        cur.execute(
            f"""
            SELECT col1, col2
            FROM test
            WHERE
                col1 BETWEEN {value1 - value2} AND {value1 + value2}
            """
        )

        rows = np.array(cur.fetchall())

        return rows
    
    def close(self):
        self.con.close()

@ray.remote(num_cpus=0.1)
def worker(db):
    num_values = 1000

    # Dummy values
    value1s = np.random.uniform(size=num_values)
    value2s = np.random.uniform(size=num_values)

    for i in range(num_values):
        query = db.query.remote(value1s[i], value2s[i])
        rows = ray.get(query)

        if len(rows):
            # Do some calculation

        # Append result to results list
    
    # Write out to file

db_handler = DatabaseHandler.remote()
workers = []

for _ in range(31):
    workers.append(worker.remote(db_handler))

ray.get(workers)
ray.get(db_handler.close.remote())
```

This works fairly well, but the running time of my code is still dominated by querying the database (which has an index on `col1`). What I would like to do is use multiple threads to query the database, but my attempts at this (e.g. setting the class wrapper to be `@ray.remote(num_cpus=2, max_concurrency=2)` and the `sqlite3.connect` to have `check_same_thread=False`) have slowed the runtime down. It's possible I'm supposed to do something to set the [memory cache to be shared](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html), but I've not managed this successfully.

I have limited experience with sqlite3, so please be explicit with any suggestions you may have. Any suggestions of alternate solutions/approaches are also very welcome.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784173/what-are-the-performance-characteristics-of-sqlite-with-very-large-database-file regarding performance issues for large sqlite databases.

Comment: Barmar, I'm not really sure what to take away from that question. The update says the contents are obsolete and I'm definitely within the SQLite size limits.

Comment: The accepted answer isn't about limits, just about performance. Removing limits due to the move to 64-bit won't make disk access faster.

Comment: I can split my data into several tables, but then I'd have to write code to query the appropriate table(s) which I think is likely to be slower than SQLite's implementation. The author of the accepted answer (also the OP) says in their update that the things that they wrote are obsolete and that SQLite now works well with large datasets. It seems unlikely to me that I'll write something faster than SQLite does, but I'll give it a go if there aren't any other ideas.

Comment: For those that come after me, I didn't manage to solve this issue. I ended up finding a domain-specific work around that meant I didn't have to query the database so many times. It's not an ideal solution, but it's enough for my purposes.